# Select and Group by fixed date interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, intervals

I'm working on a big MySQL time based statistic table.

I have a fixed time range (start and end date time objects) and get an interval string in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) interval string like `P1DT6H` as PHP object where the start date in the range is also the start point of the interval and also defines the timezone used for the interval.

Now I want to select all data within the given time range grouped by this interval but I can't make it work even after lot of hours :(

For example I get a time range of `2015-09-01/2015-09-06` and an interval of `P1DT6H` and the following example table:

```
TIMESTAMP           | count
2015-09-01 00:00:00 | 1
2015-09-01 02:00:00 | 1
2015-09-01 04:00:00 | 1
2015-09-01 06:00:00 | 1
2015-09-01 08:00:00 | 1
2015-09-01 10:00:00 | 1
2015-09-01 12:00:00 | 1
2015-09-01 14:00:00 | 1
2015-09-01 16:00:00 | 1
2015-09-01 18:00:00 | 1
2015-09-01 20:00:00 | 1
2015-09-01 22:00:00 | 1
2015-09-03 00:00:00 | 1
2015-09-03 02:00:00 | 1
2015-09-03 04:00:00 | 1
2015-09-03 06:00:00 | 1
2015-09-03 08:00:00 | 1
2015-09-03 10:00:00 | 1
2015-09-03 12:00:00 | 1
2015-09-03 14:00:00 | 1
2015-09-03 16:00:00 | 1
2015-09-03 18:00:00 | 1
2015-09-03 20:00:00 | 1
2015-09-03 22:00:00 | 1
2015-09-05 00:00:00 | 1
2015-09-05 02:00:00 | 1
2015-09-05 04:00:00 | 1
2015-09-05 06:00:00 | 1
2015-09-05 08:00:00 | 1
2015-09-05 10:00:00 | 1
2015-09-05 12:00:00 | 1
2015-09-05 14:00:00 | 1
2015-09-05 16:00:00 | 1
2015-09-05 18:00:00 | 1
2015-09-05 20:00:00 | 1
2015-09-05 22:00:00 | 1
```

With that I want to have the following result:

```
TIMESTAMP           | count
2015-09-01 00:00:00 | 12
2015-09-02 06:00:00 | 6
2015-09-03 12:00:00 | 6
2015-09-04 18:00:00 | 12
```

For sure the interval can be more complicated, the time range can be very big  and the data table is also a big table.

This needs to handle months where nearly every month have a different amount of days incl. leap year and also dst changes where a day can have 23, 24 or 25 hours. (Means a one day interval is different than a 24 hours interval)

It would be really really helpful if someone has a solution or can me point to the right direction for that kind of problem.

Thanks!

PS: I have a script that creates SQL an expression in base of a given db column, the start, end and interval objects but it only works for very simple intervals like `P1D`. I don't past it here as I don't want to ping all great brains into a non working direction that I already have ;)

What I have right now but it doesn't work with mixed intervals.
Examples:

Timezone handling:

```
if ($db->getTimezone()->getName() !== $start->getTimezone()->getName()) {
    $col = 'CONVERT_TZ(' . $col
        . ', ' . $this->quote($this->getTimezone()->getName())
        . ', ' . $this->quote($start->getTimezone()->getName())
        . ')';
}
```

`P1M`:

```
$m = ($interval->y * 12) + $interval->m;
if ($m) {
    if ($m > 1) {
        $mod  = $start->format('Ym') % $m;
        $mod  = $mod ? ' + ' . $mod : '';
        $expr = 'EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM ' . $col . ')';
        $expr = $mod ? '(' . $expr . $mod . ')' : $expr;
        $expr = ' - INTERVAL ' . $expr . ' % ' . $m . ' MONTH';
        $sqlIntervalMonth = $expr;
    }
    $sqlIntervalDay = ' - INTERVAL DAY(' . $col . ') - 1 DAY';
    if ($start->format('d') > 1) {
        $sqlIntervalDay .= ' + INTERVAL ' . ($start->format('d') - 1) . ' DAY';
    }
}
```

`P1D`:

```
$d = $interval->d;
if ($d) {
    $days = $start->diff(new DateTime('0000-00-00'))->days;
    $mod  = $days % $d;
    $mod  = $mod ? ' + ' . $mod : '';
    $expr = 'TO_DAYS(' . $col . ')';
    $expr = $mod ? '(' . $expr . $mod . ')' : $expr;
    $expr = ' - INTERVAL ' . $expr . ' % ' . $d  . ' DAY';
    $sqlIntervalDay = $expr;
}
```

*EDIT 1:* pointed out timezone, dst and leap year requirement.
*EDIT 2:* added PHP snippets

Comment: Can you clarify how you get from the data to the expected results? Can't see it myself....

Comment: That's a MySQL TIMESTAMP datatype field and the example result is exactly what I need. Handling timezones is a requirement in nearly every statistic application that shows numbers to clients. You can't simply ignore the reality that nobody lives in UTC.

Comment: I mean I havle a start point ``2015-09-01`` and an interval ``P1DT6H`` and I need to group all data together one one interval point to the next etc.

Comment: Ryan - I added the snipped for the timezone handling I have right now - see ``Timezone handling:``

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to convert the value of the time stamp to seconds and then round that value to the appropriate interval (36 hours in your case).  Something like this:

```
select min(timestamp) as timestamp, sum(count)
from t
group by floor(to_seconds(timestamp) / 60 * 60 * 36)  -- * 60 * 60 * 36
order by timestamp;
```

This uses the `min()` of the datetime value, because you seem to have that value in the table.  Alternatively, you can convert the rounded seconds back to a datetime value.

Comment: This query would not return not existing data points like ``2015-09-02 06:00:00`` and it doesn't work for dst timezones or managing month iterations because not every month has the same amount of days.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could get. Though time periods without any data will not be represented (don't know if that is a problem or not):

```
select yourTimestamp,sum(yourCount)
from
(
select t.yourTimestamp,t.yourCount,
'2015-09-01' + interval (36*60)*(floor(timestampdiff(MINUTE,'2015-09-01',t.yourTimestamp)/(36*60))) minute as recordGrpTime
from t
where t.yourTimestamp between '2015-09-01' and '2015-09-06'
) t
group by recordGrpTime;
```

Comment: Hi Tom, the problem is that 1 day != 24 hours because of dst differences